# Ручной генератор выдает 5V, кол-во ампер скорее всего зависит от скорости вращения. Портит ли нестабильность в амперах батарею?

Tags: электроника

Купил ручной генератор. должен выдавать 5V. Кол-во ампер, если правильно понимаю зависит от скорости вращения. Смартфону нужно предположим 1А и 5W. Будет ли нестабильность от ручного генератора портить батарею? Или самое главное что бы давал 5V. Мультиметра нет.

Comment: Весьма сомнительно. А вот от "должен выдавать 5 вольт" до "стабильно выдаёт 5 вольт" - увы, дистанция огромного размера. Скорее всего, на стабильность можно не рассчитывать - и вот это как раз не лучшее, что может быть при зарядке.

Comment: В современных телефонах зарядкой батареи занимается микроконтроллер, так что до некоторой степени ему всё равно какие девиации тока происходят на входе.